# Return $stateParams for dynamic title

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

I'm able to pass a router parameter when clicking a link to our 'count' page

```
$state.go('count', {targetName: object.name})
```

Because of what is established in the router as seen below:

```
url: '/count/:targetName',
```

We are using the `data:` option within UI-Router in combination with `$state` to dynamically set our page titles

```
<title ng-bind="'Application Name : ' + $state.current.data.pageTitle"></title>
```

I would like the `pageTitle` to include the `:targetName`. So in order to do that I believe i need to set a function in the `data:` property of the router. I've tried something like this:

```
data: {
    pageTitle: function () {
        getTargetName.$inject('$stateParams');
        function getTargetName ($stateParams) {
            return $stateParams.targetName;
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't allow the page to resolve at all.

Any tips?

Comment: How about you create a directive or a component which generates the title tag?

Answer (score 2):

There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Vsy7SccxsWDvxwoY0P59?p=preview)

Let's have these kinds of states

```
// this is just a state, with its own pageTitle STRING
.state('home', {
    ...
    data: {
       pageTitle: "Just a home page"
    },
})
// this is a parent state, with URL parameter 'someParam'
// nad pageTitle as a function
.state('parent', {
    ...
    url: "/parent?someParam",
    data: {
        pageTitle: function ($stateParams) {
          return `title with a param ${$stateParams.someParam}`;
        }
    }
})
// and to show that child can change it
.state('parent.child', { 
    ...
    data: {
        pageTitle: "just a child title",
    }
})
```

to make this line of code working:

```
<title>The tile is: {{ getTitle() }}  </title>
```

we can just add small evaluation into `$rootScope`, but of course, it should be some service... *take it as a simplified how to*:

```
.run(['$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams',
  function ($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {

    $rootScope.getTitle = function(){
      var state = $state.current;
      var params = $stateParams;

      if (state.data
      && state.data.pageTitle) {

        if(typeof (state.data.pageTitle) === "function" ){
          return state.data.pageTitle(params);
        }
        return state.data.pageTitle
      }
      return "no title for this state"
    }
}])
```

and all these links will have different title

```
<a href="#/home">
<a ui-sref="parent({someParam: 1})">
<a ui-sref="parent({someParam: 'someValue'})">
<a ui-sref="parent.child">
```

Check it in action [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Vsy7SccxsWDvxwoY0P59?p=preview)